# Jackson ObjectMapper in JunitTest5 returns source cannot be null

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit5

Preamble: I'm learning Java (Spring) with TDD. I have a work-in-progress project here:

Branch: https://github.com/sineverba/online-banking-backend/tree/add-controller

Last commit: https://github.com/sineverba/online-banking-backend/commit/69d643eb81748656200f007bedf213d9352b079a

I'm introducing test for POST call (see `add-controller` branch to get current state of work).

So, in new controller I added the post call and in the test I wrote:

```java
        var id = 1L;
        var transactionToSave = validBankAccountTransactionsEntity(new BigDecimal(99.99), "First Transaction");
        var savedTransaction = validBankAccountTransactionsEntity(id, new BigDecimal(99.99), "First Transaction");
        
        when(bankAccountTransactionsService.post(transactionToSave))
        .thenReturn(savedTransaction);
        
        mvc.perform(
                post("/api/v1/bank-account-transactions/")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(transactionToSave))
                )
        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is((int) id)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.amount", is(transactionToSave.getAmount())));
```

I got the error

```java
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source cannot be null
```

And the issue is with

```java
[...]
objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(transactionToSave)
[...]
```

And in particular the error is

```java
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source cannot be null
    at org.modelmapper.internal.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:53)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:404)
    at com.bitbank.controllers.v1.BankAccountTransactionsController.convertToDto(BankAccountTransactionsController.java:54)
```

So, at the end, seems error caused by `convertToDto` method called by post method of controller: `return convertToDto(savedBankAccountTransactionsEntity);`.

Cannot explain my issue, I don't know how resolve it.

I'm following a guide: https://www.mattianatali.it/come-sviluppare-rest-api-in-tdd-con-spring-boot/

You can see the author wrote same code (of course different example), about at half of page, you can see:

```java
@Test
    void create_shouldSaveTheVehicle() throws Exception {
        var vehicleId = 1L;
        var vehicleToSave = aValidVehicle();

        when(vehicleService.save(vehicleToSave))
                .thenReturn(
                        vehicleToSave
                                .toBuilder()
                                .id(vehicleId)
                                .build()
                );

        mvc.perform(
                post("/api/v1/vehicles")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(vehicleToSave))
        )
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is((int) vehicleId)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.brand", is(vehicleToSave.getBrand())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.model", is(vehicleToSave.getModel())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.year", is(vehicleToSave.getYear())));
    }
```

Where is my issue? :(

Thank you.

==================

#### 1 - Add: if I use Postman and I make the call with body

```json
{
    "amount": 100,
    "purpose": "Postman test"
}
```

it works.

Comment: Where is your entity `transactionToSave` defined? I can quess that the entity contains some fields which are lazily fetched. You try to writeToBytes outside of transaction and so it can be that the lazy fields remain null and so the serializer fails

Comment: Try to mark your test with `@Transactional` to see if ^ is the  case

Comment: It is defined here: https://github.com/sineverba/online-banking-backend/blob/69d643eb81748656200f007bedf213d9352b079a/src/test/java/com/bitbank/test/controllers/v1/BankAccountTransactionsControllerTest.java See at bottom of file

Comment: Btw, with `@Transactional` I have another error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to retrieve PlatformTransactionManager for @Transactional test: [DefaultTestContext@64b73e7a testClass = BankAccountTransactionsControllerTest, testInstance = `

Comment: Try to remove the `Double getAmount()` method from your `BankAccountTransactionsDTO`

Comment: Yes, the test without the getAmount() works. But why? And overall, I have other troubles in the test without the converting value...

Overall, with Postman my controller worked.

Comment: @galaxy please, can you explain me why without the getAmount method it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you got this error is beacuse your `Double getAmount()` method overrides your default Lombok's getter and when the mapper tries to map your entity's `BigDecimal amount` with your DTO's `amount` the mapper does not find a `BigDecimal` property with `amount` as its name.

Comment: This is same idea I got. But... Why out of test (using with Postman) it worked?